# Try to figure out relation between null space and range space of two matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra

If A and B are two matrices and N (A)
 is a subspace of N(B) then Prove that  Row space of A is a subspace of row space of B., where N denoted as a Null space

Comment: The row space of any matrix is orthogonal to its null space, and $R(A) \oplus N(A) = V$, where $V$ is your whole vector space (the domain of $A$ and $B$). Do some dimension counting or throw some basis vectors around?

Comment: Hm.. If $N(A)$ is a substance of $N(B)$, then $dim(N(A)) < dim(N(B))$ implying $dim(R(A)) > dim(R(B))$. So how can $R(A)$ be a subspace of $R(B)$?

Comment: Bare problem statements like this one, with no context or any visible effort at solving the problem yourself, look a lot like you’re trying to outsource your schoolwork and are not well-received here. You should update your question with your own attempts at a solution, or with what it is that you have to work with so that anyone who wants to help you can give you an answer that you’ll understand. Without that, there’s a good change that this question will be closed. See [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).